# Is It Possible to Use BotDetect Captcha in .NET 7 with a Linux Host?

Tags: c#, linux, azure, captcha, botdetect

BotDetect Captcha seems to be using System.Drawing.Common which--as of .NET 7--is no longer usable when running on Linux.

Is there an option I've overlooked?